# Relationship hasManyThrough in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have three models: `User, Category, Announcement`.

User model:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Category");
    }

    public function announcements()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Announcement', 'App\Category');
    }
```

Category model:

```
public function announcements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Announcement');
    }
```

Announcement model:

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
```

I need to select all announcements through `user_categories` table.

For this I do:

```
$res = User::where("id", 1)->with("announcements")->get();
dd($res);
```

In result I get SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'announcements.category_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `announcements`.*, `categories`.`user_id` from `announcements` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `announcements`.`category_id` where `categories`.`user_id` in (1) and `announcements`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Why Laravel does try to search ``announcements`.`category_id` in table?

In conclusion I need to get all announcements on categories which user subscribed.

Table Database structure:

```
Users
id | name

Announcements
id | name

categories
category_id | announcement_id 

users_categories
category_id | user_id
```

So, I need to get all announcements through table users_categories where there are `relation` this table with `categories` that is belong to `announcement` table.

Comment: is this a type of ORM and does it do fetching based on assumed column names to match the foreign key? If so I think this may be what is happening. It is trying to retrieve all the "many" announcements and therefore categories via propagation assuming the column names are [tablename]_id. Just a quick guess though.

Comment: Maybe there is an good sample?

Comment: As for the query do you have a `category_id` in `announcements` table? What is the table structure?

Comment: @Darama post your database structure for those three models

Comment: Seeing that user has a relation with both category and announcement, this is not the usecase for a `hasManyThrough` relation. What you want can be accomplished by using `User::where("id", 1)->with("categories.announcements")->get();` and setting the pivot table `user_categories` in your relation properly.

Comment: I have updated question, look please again with was added tables structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot eager load this relationship because

> To perform this query, Eloquent inspects the foreign key on the intermediate table.

Thus the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'announcements.category_id'

Because `HasManyThrough()` looks for the relationship in the specified model table.

I would suggest you look at this thread:
https://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-problem-with-eloquents-hasmanythroughs-query

They show you how to write your own query to do that. An example would be, in the user model do

```
public function getAnnouncements() {
    $announcements = [];
    foreach( $this->categories as $category ) {
        foreach( $category->announcements as $annoucement ) {
            if ( !isset($announcements[$annoucement->id]) ) { //avoid duplicates
                $annoucements[$announcement->id] = $announcement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The nested foreach will give all announcement belonging to a category that related to a user.

Improving the function

```
public function getAnnouncements() {
    $announcements = new Collection();
    foreach( $this->categories as $category ) {
        $announcements->collect($category->announcements);
    }
}
```